# Kivy doesn't return values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

```
#:kivy 1.11.1 

<MyManager>:
    ConnPage:
    MyGame:

<ConnPage>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 4

            Label:
                text: "username: "

            TextInput:
                id: username
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "password: "

            TextInput:
                id: password
                password: True
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "email: "

            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mygame" if password.text == "password" else "main" 
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<MyGame>:
    name: "mygame"

    Button:
        text: "Go back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os
import sys

kivy.require("1.11.1")

class ConnPage(Screen):
    def login(self):
        user = self.root.ids.username.text
        passw = self.root.ids.password.text
        mail = self.root.ids.email.text
        print(f"{user}")
        if len(user) > 0 and len(passw) > 0 and len(mail) > 0:
            from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
            import urllib.parse
            parameters = {"username":user, "password":passw, "email":mail}
            parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)
            header = {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept":"text/plain"}
            url = "http://localhost/2D_kivy_game/login.php"
            UrlRequest(url=url, req_headers=header, req_body=parameters, on_success=self.success, on_error=self.error)
        print("Please fill in all values!!!!")

    def success(self, req, data):
        print(data)

    def error(self, req, errormessage):
        print(errormessage)

class MyGame(Screen):
    pass

class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("stylesheet.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

---

The Problem I have is that the program doesn't return the requested value's.
Getting the values is done in my .kv file 
The program does run the classes but doesn't return the values I assume you can't ask for MyManager() and suspect it to return sub class values...?
Im using kivy 1.11.1 maybe it doesn't work on this version? 
I have no idea, have been trying to fix this for 4 days now it its starting to work on my nerves since I don't get any feedback in the terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - what line do you expect to "return values"?

Comment: I expect the user, passw, mail to be return because they don't seem to be returned

Comment: Where is the code that calls `login()`?

Comment: that's probably my mistake, i never called it. And where do I need to call it?

Comment: It's your code, where do you want it to be called?

Comment: It should be whenever the login button is pressed